# Open google maps POI links in system browser

Tags: android, ios, cordova, google-maps, ionic-framework

I have a huge problem with my ionic app. 
When the user clicks on a point of interest, for example train stations and clicks on "open in Google Maps" The App opens the link fullscreen in the app and you have to kill the app, since there is no close button. The Softkeys don't work.

See here:

[image]

I guess I have to use the inappbrowser, but how can I enable it inside the map? Deactivating the POI's isn't an option.

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

In my case i had in controller.js:

```
'<a onclick="goto('+obj1[j].places.items[0][0]+','+obj1[j].places.items[0][1]+')">Open in google maps!</a>'
```

and then in function goto:

```
window.goto = function(lat,lon){
     window.open("https://www.google.com/maps/dir//"+lat+","+lon+"/@",'_system', 'location=yes');          
}
```

Edit:

(....your code....)

```
 var popupContent1 = '<div id="locationContent1">' +                        
      '<div> ' + item.storeName + '</div>' +
      '<div> ' + item.address + '</div>' +
      '<div> ' + item.city + '</div>' +

      '<div>' +'<a onclick="goto('+item.latitude+','+item.longitude+')">Open in google maps!</a>'+ '</div>' +
      '</div>';


 createInfoWindow(marker, popupContent1);   

 //marker.bindTo('map',cat.data('goo'),'map');
 var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  function createInfoWindow(marker, popupContent1) {
           google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'click',function(){                                              infowindow.setContent(popupContent1);
                      infowindow.open(map,this);
            })
  }
```

Comment: Thank you, but I think i can't use this. There is no HTML for the go to google maps, since this is implemented in standard google maps API. I don't create the go to google maps links.

Comment: I understand. But you can configure this. All you need is the lat and lot for the poi. Then you can create yours "open in google maps" with a function.

Comment: Could you help me a bit with it? This is what my map controller looks like: https://gist.github.com/patrickhofer/bf4546118a5e05d1e0cbafc255775218

Comment: Please tell me if this solved your problem. As you can see its a custom solution but for me it works perfect!

Comment: no this won't work, since i have to diffrent markers. My custom markers and the markers which are provided from google maps. Is there even a soution when I have two different markers?

Comment: I don't understand the reason. If you add the code inside a loop and for each loop, you have a marker and an infowindow with the information about the poi i think that works. I dont have any other solution. Hope you find the answer mate!

Comment: Thank you anyways! I now just hide the go to google maps link with css. :)